# Neo4j Query Optimization for Relations+Nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph data and this data includes millions of data. I try to figure out query optimization methods in neo4j.

For example, I have a query like:

```
MATCH ((a1:App{appId:1}) <- [:PAID_BY] - (k:Keyword{countryCode:'US'}) - [:PAID_BY] -> (a2:App{appId:2}))
return distinct k.value
limit 50
```

For this query optimization, which indexes should I create it? Or is there any optimization way for this query?

Note: In this query, I try to find mutual keywords between two apps.

Comment: I suggest editing your question to show what issues you're having. Also, "how to optimize" is fairly broad and open-ended.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is collecting keywords that are common between app1 and app2. You can create indices on App.appId and Keyword.countryCode. Then use this query.

```
RETURN apoc.coll.toSet( 
 [ (:App{appId:1}) <- [:PAID_BY] - 
 (k:Keyword{countryCode:'US'}) - 
 [:PAID_BY] -> (:App{appId:2}) | k.value]) as keywords


 Where apoc.col.toSet will ensure that the list have unique values
 [ ] is called comprehension and similar to collect() function
 | or pipe is a way to filter data. So you list will contain keyword.value
```

We love APOC functions and one liner code, isn't?